# How to restore data from a Formatted HDD

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I was installing Kali linux without knowing that I was using my personal HDD to do so. Now I have formatted the data that was present on HDD.

I want to know, Is there a way to restore the data that was on it by myself? If not then what should I do now.

The HDD in question is Seagate Barracuda 1 TB Internal Hard Drive HDD 3.5 Inches SATA 6 Gb/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have formatted and then overwritten the disk with a new installation, your chances of recovery are much diminished if not impossible for all practical purposes.

Try Recuva (Wondershare) to see if that works.

Otherwise you need to depend upon backups.

Comment: John, I have the utmost respect for your tremendous contributions to the Super User community!  However, I intentionally waited until after the holidays to ask this question:  although you are clearly very proactive when it comes to answering questions, do you **ever** actually check to see if the queries that you answer are duplicates?  This has happened with you many times before, and it is difficult to imagine that someone with your impressive level of Windows knowledge wouldn't realize that *How to restore data from a formatted HDD"* has been asked within the Super User realm many times.

Comment: I look for recent duplicates.  I see too many duplicates reported from nearly a decade ago that often do not well fit the situation.  I probably see this differently than you (and some others).  You can delete if that is your preference.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but this really is a rather remedial question.  Please don't get me wrong, though... you still provided a good answer!  But this is *such* a common question, and it's a shame to bog down Super User with yet *another* Q&A for a redundant topic like this.  The author was brand-new to Super User, so they might be forgiven for their lapse of effort and/or research, but hopefully one of our very best subject matter experts could help point them in the right direction rather than enabling them by answering anyway.